# LWC Component not working. Trouble passing parameter to APEX

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have to admit its been a while since I wrote an LWC component. I have the HTML which basically loads a different page (view) depending on if a condition is true. There is one part of my JS which is not working and as a result it is no longer loading any of the pages. I believe I am passing the variable from the LWC to apex incorrectly. The parameter is the recordId (which is the accId). I am calling a JS function that passes this accountId to apex. The apex checks if that account has a certain field (Order_Confirmation__c which is a checkbox) as true or not. If it is, then it loads a page and if it is false it loads a different page. Everything was working great. Then I added the below piece of JS and now nothing is loading(obviously I am only providing that snippet which contains the JS function and not all JS for relevance). Here is my Apex:

```
global class ApexCtrl {
    
    @AuraEnabled
    global static Account getOrderSubmitted(Id accId){
        Account acc = [SELECT Id, Name, Order_Confirmation__c, Feedback_Confirmation__c FROM Account WHERE Id =: accId];
        return acc;
    }
}
```

Here is my JS for the LWC:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import AccountHasOrder from '@salesforce/apex/APEXCtrl.getOrderSubmitted';

export default class MylWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement){
    @track virtualSellingFirst; 
    @track virtualSellingThankyou; 
    @track FeedbackThankyou;
    @track virtualSellingNoGUID;
    @track accountData;
    @track productRecord;
    @track error;

    @api acId;
    connectedCallback() {
        this.acId = '';

        const param = 'c__recordId';
        const paramValue = this.getUrlParamValue(window.location.href, param);
        console.log('to show my parm :: '+paramValue);

        //this.productNameGet();
        if(paramValue == null || paramValue == ''){
            this.acId = '';
            this.virtualSellingFirst = false; 
            this.virtualSellingNoGUID = true;
        }else{
            this.acId = paramValue;
            OrderAlreadySubmitted();  //Am I calling this properly
            //this.virtualSellingFirst = true; 
            //this.virtualSellingNoGUID = false;
        }
    }

OrderAlreadySubmitted(){
        AccountHasOrder({
            accId: this.acId
        })
        .then(result => {
            this.accountData = result;

            if(this.accountData.Order_Confirmation__c == true){
                this.virtualSellingFirst = false; 
                this.virtualSellingNoGUID = false;
                this.VirtualSellingThankyou = true;
                this.FeedbackThankyou = false;

            }else if(this.accountData.Feedback_Confirmation__c == true){
                this.virtualSellingFirst = false; 
                this.virtualSellingNoGUID = false;
                this.VirtualSellingThankyou = false;
                this.FeedbackThankyou = true;

            } else if(this.accountData.Feedback_Confirmation__c == true && this.accountData.Order_Confirmation__c == true){ //not sure if ths condition is needed
                this.virtualSellingFirst = false; 
                this.virtualSellingNoGUID = false;
                this.VirtualSellingThankyou = true;
                this.FeedbackThankyou = false;
            } else{
                this.virtualSellingFirst = true; 
                this.virtualSellingNoGUID = false;
                this.VirtualSellingThankyou = false;
                this.FeedbackThankyou = false;
            }
        })

    }

    
}
```

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Did you check your browser console log to see for any exceptions? And what is being returned in `accountData`, can you paste that too.

Comment: it should be `this.OrderAlreadySubmitted();`. I presume that's what you mean when you say it's not working? Or do you get a specific error message?

Comment: I am not getting any error message. The page just doesnt show up. When I revert my code back (remove the new JS function) the pages start to show. (I put this js code to display a new page i added)

Comment: I am getting an error message that the query is returning nothing. So The page just doesnt show up. When I revert my code back (remove the new JS function) the pages start to show. (I put this js code to display a new page i added). Thats why i think i am not passing the accId properly to the orderalreadysubmited function

Comment: do you have a value in `this.acId`? Is `paramValue` working - I would guess it isn't. Is this LWC within a different component or are you navigating to a specific URL for it? I would avoid using `window.location` and look at properly doing query parameters for [LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_add_params_url)

Comment: @kris goncalves This.acId is working for other scenarios. Paramvalues was working too. But this.acId inside this order submitted function is not seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reassign value to an api property. Please try adding another property with getter and setter to access the public property **acId**. I would also suggest to use **CurrentPageReference** from the navigation module to access the URL and URL Params as suggested by @Kris Goncalves.